# Tool to migrate Azure storage to local development storage

Tags: azure-storage

Are there any good tools to take a snapshot of my Azure tables and blob containers and copy it into local development storage?

Developers sometimes need to work in a isolated environment but would like a copy of some "real" application data. Right now we have data creation scripts that we can run to populate local storage but it would be helpful to be able to grab a snapshot and move into development storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use [Cloud Storage Studio](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/cloudstoragestudio/) for all handling of Azure Storage. Using that you can easily download from your live blob storage and then upload to your local storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Azure Storage Synctool](http://azurestoragesynctool.powerybase.com/) to upload the local storage to a live storage blob on Azure, or download (vice versa).